# Notepad++ Regex to bookmark lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have list of lines structured like this

```
c:\names1\ex1
c:\names2\ex2
c:\names3\ex14
http://example1
http://example3
c:\names4\ex15
http://example4
c:\names4\ex17
c:\names4\ex18
```

I want to use Regex to mark all lines which followed by c:\ as a start of line not http, In this case the first two lines and the last two lines should be marked.
Because the others "lines started with c: too" followed by http:\ as a start of line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to perform this.

1. Go to **Search** > **Find**... > Select the **Mark** Tab. Make sure you have Regular expression checked under the Search Mode box and make sure you check the **Bookmark Line** box.
2. You want to search for the following, still being under the **Mark** tab.

   ```
   Find what: ^c:\S++(?!\r?\nhttp)
   ```
3. Finally, click **Mark All** which bookmarks those lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
^c:.*+(?!\r?\nhttp:)
```

pattern details:

```
^                # anchor for the start of the line
c:      
.*+              # zero or more characters until the end of line (possessive)
(?!\r?\nhttp:)   # not followed by a newline and http:
```